# How to set environment variable for Azure Databricks cluster which is triggered from ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a python script, which check whether APP_HOME directory is set as the environment variable or not and picks up few files in this directory to proceed with the further execution.

If it is running on windows, I am setting the environment variable pointing to APP_HOME directory. If the python script is created as a workflow in databricks, the workflow is giving me an option to set the environment variables while choosing the cluster for the task.

But, If the python script runs as a Databricks python activity from Azure Data factory, I have not found an option to set the environment variable for the databricks cluster that will be created by ADF. Is there a way to set up the environment variable APP_HOME in ADF for databricks cluster when Databricks python activity is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created data factory and created pipeline in data factory. I added data bricks as linked services linked service.
fill the required fields in additional settings of cluster will find environment variable field.

Reference image:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Amareswarapu Bhavani. Thank you very much for the answer. I have a follow up question though. If I have to change or edit the environment variable, instead of editing the linked service, can it point out to a file in blob storage and get the value from there? Lets say, today I want to set the environment variable to "/dbfs/path/to/file" and run the pipeline. After few days, I may want to edit the env variable. so instead of editing the linked service, is there a possibility to only change value in the blob file which can be read by linked service?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to do it dynamically. first create a linked service parameter and give that to this dynamic content. While executing you can give that value to that parameter.